# Finding the parent class using Child identity in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Myself finding the particular URL in the Google results and I want to find the rich snippet (Star rating) displayed under the URL in the Google results page.

I have found the URL match using the following:

```
List<WebElement> listings = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div").xpath("//cite[@class='_Rm bc']"));
```

But I don't know how to find the parent class using this listing so that I can navigate to the next div and find whether the star rating is displayed or not.

Comment: Share your code with some details, using which we can help you .

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys(Product_Name[i]);
  driver.findElement(By.id("_fZl")).click();
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  
  List<WebElement> listings = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div").xpath("//cite[@class='_Rm bc']"));
     listings.size();
     System.out.println("Fetched URL's are as follows:-");
     String Product_URl_trim = Site_Url[i].replaceAll("\\s","");

Comment: for(WebElement loop :listings)
     {
      String URLText = loop.getText();
      String URLText_Trim = URLText.replaceAll("\\s","");
      
      System.out.println(URLText_Trim);
      System.out.println(Product_URl_trim);
      if(URLText_Trim==Product_URl_trim)
      {
       
       System.out.println(URLText);
       WebElement child = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//cite[@class='_Rm bc']"));
       WebElement parent = child.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
       WebElement Parent_1 = parent.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
       System.out.println(Parent_1);
      }
     }

Comment: the above two comments contains the complete code kindly review and give me suggestion.

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html - Refer this page you ll get some idea.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot.

Comment: I Have another issue like i can find the element using following  //cite[contains(text(),"https://www.g-loves.com/wonder-w-wrist-wraps")]  but when i run using this java selenium script like driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),"https://www.g-loves.com/wonder-w-wrist-wraps)]")).isDisplayed()   it fails to identify. Kindly Suggest me how can i handle this

Comment: The element is present and still it fails to find? if so, check the xpath once again.